# replace a character into awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I use ${var//string1/string2} for replace characters or strings, now I need do the same but in a specific column awk.

try this for replace space per '_' but does not work

```
cat file | awk -F',' '{print ${3// /_}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [gsub](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(" ", "_", $3); print}' file.txt
```